Cannot login into Wayland Gnome session Ubuntu Jammy with Mali GPU
I am using Mali Bifrost G52 GPU & can login in X11 session but when trying Wayland I am always thrown back to login screen of gdm3. The following contains output of dmesg lsmod & journalctl -f while trying to login Wayland session. As you can see panfrost is enabled & is shown at output of glxinfo -B
I have enabled gdm3 debug option
Side note I can login into Kodi Wayland & it correctly identifies windowing system as gbm instead of X11
https://pastebin.com/Rkx1YWsx
